# How do I prove that $S^1 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a group?

Tags: group-theory

Define
$$ S^1 = \{\mathrm{e}^{i2\pi t} \in \mathbb{C} \mid t \in [0, 1]\}. $$
Show that $S^1$
is a subgroup of $(C \setminus \{0\}, \times)$.

I know there has to be an identity element and I have shown that taking $t=0$ gives an identity.  I'm struggling to prove if $g \in S^1$, then $g^{-1} \in S^1$, and also if $g,h \in S^1$ then $gh \in S^1$.

I've proved it is a homomorphism also and need to use this to prove that $(\mathrm{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}, +) \simeq (S^1, \times)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$g=e^{2\pi it}\;,\;\;0\le t\le 1\implies g^{-1}=e^{-2\pi it}=e^{2\pi i(1-t)}\;,\;\;0\le1-t\le 1$$

Comment: So for h would i just call t something different like use k and prove it using k?

Comment: @Pkr96 What? What I showed is that the inverse of an element in $\;S^1\;$ is also an element of $\;S^1\;$ by your definition...

Comment: Yeah i get that i was asking about g*h being an element of s1

Comment: @Pkr96 Just like above: $$e^{2\pi it}\cdot e^{2\pi ik}=e^{2\pi i(t+k)}$$ and if $\;t+k\le1\;$ we're done, **otherwise** $$t+k=1+r\;,\;\;0\le r\le 1\implies e^{2\pi i(t+k)}=e^{2\pi ir}$$ and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

In complement, here is another way of proving that $\mathbb{S}^1$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{C} \smallsetminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace, \times)$. If $G$ and $G'$ are two groups and $f \, : \, G \, \rightarrow \, G'$ a group homomorphism, then:

- $\mathrm{Im}(f) = \lbrace f(g), \, g \in G \rbrace$ is a subgroup of $G'$,
- $\mathrm{ker}(f) = \lbrace g \in G, \, f(g) = 1_{G'} \rbrace$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Here, consider :

$G = (\mathbb{R},+)$, $G'=(\mathbb{C} \smallsetminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace, \times)$ and $f \, : \, G \, \rightarrow \, G'$ such that : $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \, f(t) = \exp(2i\pi t)$.